# Access by multiple users to access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am not very familiar with Access database till now i was only programming to SQL Server but now it's time to do so. I am building WinForms application which will be using Access database and i have some question related to that point if you don't mind. My application will be used by multiple users and there will be one access databsae. My questions as below:

> 1. Is there any problem with accessing access database in same time by many users or only one user can be connected?
> 2. If i develop my program to use access 2016 and some of my users will have diffrent windows version and also diffrent access version
>      will it works?
> 3. Should i know something else? :)

Comment: How many is "many users" (at one time)?  Is this on the web, a Lan or what?

Comment: Maybe this will help you [Access vs. Sql Server Express](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7b8d24c7-64ab-42cf-978a-1e5c896f7e41/access-vs-sql-server-express?forum=sqlexpress) From personal experience I strongly suggest not using Access.

Answer (score 1):

If your client want to have a file based database and this is a project constraint , MS Access is the best choice. If you want a more detailed advice, please let me know how many users will perform Read/Write or Read transactions, the size of the database and if the application will run in client-server mode in a LAN/WAN, Cloud or Remote Desktop environment.

Back to your questions:

1. Depending on these conditions you may range from 10 to 20/25 users. Remember that you can always try with MS Access and later upgrade to a MS SQL database in a couple of hours.
2. If your front-end application can link to a 2016 Access database, it will do that without installing MS Access to the clients that will run your App, i.e. the vb.net compiled App will install all needed drivers. If you develop your App within MS Access 2016 (Access Form and reports, some VBA) you can run it with the free runtime version of MS Access, but this only when no older version of Access is installed on the running workstation.
3. Please check with your client the real reasons for a file-based database...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions as asked:

1. You might run into an issue with this, as access was really designed as a personal use database.  Having anything more than a small handful of users hitting against it at once will in fact cause problems, as it's not really well designed for that purpose...
2. This should in theory be fine, as the application itself is interfacing with the database, not the end user...
3. It seems like you're taking a step backwards using access for this, and SQL might very well be better suited for this purpose.  This isn't me trying to just bash access either, this comes from personal experience.  Going with this sort of design is likely to cause you more headaches than good.

Comment: the purpose is my client wants to have database within file - but he doesn;t say about access.. Maybe its better to choose SQL Lite or SQL Compact what do you think? I am not so familiar with SQL Server Compact - is this stored in file? Can i provide then it on pendrive with the app or not?

Comment: I'm not particularly well versed with those, but I'd say either of those would likely make a better choice than access.

Comment: Check out this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/user_ed/archive/2012/12/09/how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx

Comment: Let's assume forget about SQL Server even embded. In this particural situation which selection you would pick if you were me either SQL Lite or SQL Server Compact? Does any of them provide no problem with multiple users access (and lock..?)?

Comment: SQL compact edition does not allow multi-user. SQL lite to my knowledge does. It not quite clear why they want a file based system. If  you going file based, then Access is a ok choice due to allowing multi-user. The reason being is most file based systems don't allow multiple users. I would consider using SQL server, since it works rather well with visual studio.

Comment: i am bit confused. Its clear then that SQL Compact does not allow multi user. You said SQl Lite allows that so i should consider it. Not clear about Access you said it is multi user (no locks then when some user is occuping  access file?) and other user on this forum said its not allowing multiuser access so how then it is with it?

Comment: @JohnDoe - The Access Database Engine does indeed support read/write access to the database from a limited number of concurrent remote users. (The practical limit varies depending on the circumstances, but 10 is often used as a ballpark figure.) SQLite supports multiple concurrent readers but only one connection can write to the database at any given time. SQL Server CE is designed for *local* database storage so an application with multiple remote connections should use SQL Server Express instead of SQL Server CE.

Comment: i think i use sql lite then instead - i am still thinking also fro access - so you mean for example 5 users use access file will be not problem or yes?

Comment: That's really dependent on how much data you're going to be attempting to pull (is it a data heavy application?) and if there's a possibility for the application to EVER have to scale up to beyond the scope of what MS Access can reasonably handle.